# Why AVAudioSession is not connected after GSM call ends,While VoIP call is going on?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, avaudiosession

I make voip call from one user(X) to another(Y). When Y answers the call audio is activated.

```
Sending signal connect set to sound devices!!

Turning cap_dev -1  play_dev -2 
app_config cap_dev -1  play_dev -1 16:17:52.265            pjsua_aud.c !Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-1
16:17:52.265            pjsua_app.c  .Turning sound device -1 -2 ON
16:17:52.265            pjsua_aud.c  .Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
16:17:52.265        coreaudio_dev.c  ..Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
16:17:52.824        coreaudio_dev.c  ..core audio stream started

 after setting device status_code is 0
Turning cap_dev -1  play_dev -2
```

When GSM call comes,user X presses hold and accept option. This time audio is deactivated.

```
Sending signal to disconnect from sound devices!!
16:21:25.858            pjsua_app.c !.Turning sound device -1 -2 OFF
```

When GSM call ends audio is activated again.

```
pjsua_aud.c !Set sound device: capture=0, playback=0
16:45:45.131            pjsua_app.c  .Turning sound device 0 0 ON
16:45:45.131            pjsua_aud.c  .Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
16:45:45.132        coreaudio_dev.c  ..Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
[aurioc] 1029: failed: '!pri' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16>)
16:45:45.394            pjsua_aud.c  .Unable to open sound device: Unknown error -560577449
```

I tried with 0,0 and -1,-2 but getting same error.I am not able to hear any audio after gsm call ends.How to fix this.Any hit will be helpful for me.Thanks in advance.